# Utilizing a class that is passed to another class

Tags: python-3.x

I am not sure if I have a problem with my Logic or a coding issue.

I am working with dozens of CSV files that contain metadata about digital objects.   The first part of my script determines which CSV files are relevant and which columns I care about.   That works.

I place the information in a series of classes.    After that work I am attempting to pass a class object to another class, that once assembled will get passed on to a processing script.   When I attempt to work with the nested or passed class I get the following error "'NoneType' object has no attribute"

Simplified version of the Code

```
class csv1Cols ():
        def __init__(self, drd):
            self.drd = drd
            
class procObject ():
        def __init__(self,csv1,other):
            self.csv1 = csv1
            self.other = other

csv1 = csv1Cols(drd = 14)
other = "more data"

object = procObject (csv1=csv1, other=other)
```

When I try to access csv1 in 'object', everything I do fails?   Usually I get a the "'NoneType' object has no attribute" error.   Is this a logical error in my thinking or am I just not utilizing this passed (nested) class correctly.

I have tried code like:

```
print(f'{object.csv1}')
print(f'{object.csv1.drd}')
```

Comment: Which line in this code does the error message come from?

Comment: I didn't include the code snippet that doesn't work because I assumed I am doing something wrong.

Comment: And now we are supposed to tell you what is wrong with the code you didn't show?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs for me when I copy and paste it as written (running with Python3.9, but it shouldn't make a difference as long as you are using at least Python3.6 to support f-strings).

An issue that might be causing you trouble somewhere is using `object` as a variable name. As you can see in the code in your question, `object` is highlighted differently because it is a builtin class which is the base class any class you create. You may be causing issues by resetting this name to a distinct object in your code. A more descriptive variable name would be better, but in the short term you could just change it to `obj` to avoid the name conflict.

As an issue of terminology, you aren't passing a class to class or nesting classes. You are creating an instance of the class `csv1Cols`, then you are passing this instance to the constructor of `procObject` to make an instance of this class.

Comment: Thank You.  I wanted to verify that my logic was working.    I thought it should work how I was writing it, but kept failing.  I had assumed after two days that my logic was wrong and I was looking for a different solution.   Knowing it was correct, I found "MY" error.